# Why I can not update Linux core in dockers?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, lxc, docker

When I run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

in container, the core is not starting to update.

Yes, I know, containers use the kernel of host machine and can not execute some administrative task. However I've expect to get some error during the new kernel installation in container.

Instead of that, I have no message about new linux-headers package downloads or installation. It's look like the repositories with kernel sources are disabled. But all files in `/etc/apt/`are the same like on the host machine.

Comment: The kernel isn't installed in the container.  Notice that `dpkg -l | grep linux` does not show `linux`, `linux-image`, or `linux-headers`.  `apt-get upgrade` won't upgrade packages that are not installed.